# Overflow scroll doesn't work when using one page scroll JQ plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scroll

I'm using [one page scroll jquery plugin](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html) and it works great but I have a div in the first section contains a lot of data so it has a scroll bar also.
The problem is when I want to scroll in that div I scroll to the next section!

```
<section>
    <ul style="display:block;width:100px;height:300px;overflow:scroll">
        <li>item #1</li>
        <li>item #2</li>
        <li>item #3</li>
        ...
    </ul>
</section>
<section>
    another data
</section>
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else experiencing this same issue, I ended up finding the answer on my own by using slimScroll jQuery plugin.